Strongly Typed Reactive Form: Correct usage?
I am currently experimenting with Strongly Typed Reactive Forms in Angular.
I have defined an interface:
interface Data {
  name: string;
  mobile: number;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}`

And here is my component:
export class ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup<{
    name: FormControl<string>;
    mobile: FormControl<number>;
    isAdmin: FormControl<boolean>;
  }>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl<string>('', {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
      mobile: new FormControl<number>(0, {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
      isAdmin: new FormControl<boolean>(false, { nonNullable: true }), // Boolean field
    });
  }

  addValues() {
    const name = this.form.get('name').value;
    const mobile = this.form.get('mobile').value;
    console.log(name + mobile);
  }
}

I am trying to ensure type saftey, attempting to add name and mobile is my test however I am not getting the expected compilation errors:
TS18048: name is possibly undefined
TS18048: mobile is possibly undefined

How can they possibly be undefined if ive declared their type as number and string respectively
Shouldn't there be a type error when trying add string and number
Is it possible to elimnate some of this boiler plate using formBuilder / nonNullableFormBuiler class instances through dependency injection?

Cheers

Maybe use something like this with DI?
import { NonNullableFormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

interface FormModel {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

constructor(private fb: NonNullableFormBuilder) {}

const form: FormGroup = this.fb.group<FormModel>({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  age: 0,
});

also, adding string and numbers are ok in Javascript and Typescript.
If you want to ensure that added value is a number you can just do something like this
addValues() {
    const name = this.form.get('name').value;
    const mobile = this.form.get('mobile').value;
    const res: number = name + mobile; //  you get the type error here        
    console.log(res);
}

